# Escape curly brace input from form c#

Tags: c#

I know that in order to use curly braces with String.Format, I have to use double curly braces, i.e. "{{" and "}}". My question is, how do I make this work with a string that comes from a form? I've tried

```
str.Replace("{","{{");
str.Replace("}","}}");
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have to? Usually, when you receive a string internally (i.e. you're not manually hardcoding the string), it should already be formatted correctly. So I ask again, do you have to?

Comment: Is it just not working or is it doing something crazy?

Comment: @Nolonar: This is not an escape sequence, so it is not applying here. Even if that string comes from the UI, this replacement is necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String is an [immutable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Immutability). You have to reassign the corrected string back into `str`

```
str = str.Replace("{","{{");
str = str.Replace("}","}}");
```

Comment: +1 - You can also chain replace. `str = str.Replace("{","{{").Replace("}","}}");`

Comment: Yeah, I'm one to to that. Much to the chagrin of my professors, I liked chaining method calls pretty deep. ;)

Comment: Wow, that was a simple fix... it's early. Thanks for the answer. I'll mark this as soon as it will allow me.

Answer (score 3):

`str.Replace` doesn't change `str`. It returns a new instance.

So you might want to try this instead:

```
str = str.Replace(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
    str = str.Replace("{","{{");
    str = str.Replace("}","}}");
```